# JSON array convert to PHP Array

Tags: php, json

I have a json object array. I want to read the this value. how to read value using php.
My json object Array

```
[{"employeeId":"ioc-nugegoda","employeeEmail":"lankaioc@lankaioc.com","employeeName":"Colombo","employeePhoneNum":"12345","employeeBrithday":1334946600000,"employeeHomeTown":"ykjld"},{"employeeId":"ioc-nugeqqq","employeeEmail":"lankaioc@lankaioc.com","employeeName":"Colombo","employeePhoneNum":"12345","employeeBrithday":1334946600000,"employeeHomeTown":"ykjld"},{"employeeId":"ioc-nusqq","employeeEmail":"lankaioc@lankaioc.com","employeeName":"Colombo","employeePhoneNum":"12345","employeeBrithday":1334946600000,"employeeHomeTown":"ykjld"}]
```

Comment: [`json_decode()`](http://json_decode)?

Comment: what is 'the this value'? :o

Comment: I used json_decode() and print the value using php echo function then give the result as Array . How to read the value.

Answer (score 1):

```
$jsonObject = json_decode('{"employeeId":"ioc-nugegoda","employeeEmail":"lankaioc@lankaioc.com","employeeName":"Colombo","employeePhoneNum":"12345","employeeBrithday":1334946600000,"employeeHomeTown":"ykjld"},{"employeeId":"ioc-nugeqqq","employeeEmail":"lankaioc@lankaioc.com","employeeName":"Colombo","employeePhoneNum":"12345","employeeBrithday":1334946600000,"employeeHomeTown":"ykjld"},{"employeeId":"ioc-nusqq","employeeEmail":"lankaioc@lankaioc.com","employeeName":"Colombo","employeePhoneNum":"12345","employeeBrithday":1334946600000,"employeeHomeTown":"ykjld"}');
```

Which you can find [**here**](http://php.net/manual/de/function.json-decode.php). After that you can access all values of the json object by its key:

```
echo $jsonObject["employeeId"];
//Should return: ioc-nugegoda
```

If you have an array arround your JsonObject you need to access the object itself first.. this would look like:

```
echo $jsonObject[0]["employeeId"];
```

Comment: I used json_decode() and print the value using php echo function then give the result as Array . How to read the value

Comment: @TharinduDhanushka adjusted